# Receive data via url Get

Tags: php, get

I am trying to receive data via url, but I have this question of how to receive this url

```
localhost:8080/?action&p[4]=2&p[7]=5&p[12]=0&p[15]=1
```

I need the values ​​of

```
[2] = 4

2
and
4
```

Comment: [How to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try adding a simple `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,1) . '</pre>';` as the first line of your script

Comment: just `print_r($_GET);` in your php file you will get array of all parameters
if you want specific then `print_r($_GET['p']);`

Comment: thanks, more like I can get the values p​​[15] o 15 int

Comment: I already tried to use this, but I can not recover the values ​​between the []

Comment: Do you want to get values of all p in URL along with 4 and 7 located in p[4] and p[7] that you want in other variable?

Comment: yes,
the value between [] represents an ID from my database, I need to retrieve it, to check one by one.

Comment: Done, You will get the value between [] in value 2 of my answer.Please check.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you getting all data of `p` variable and the data enclosed within [] from URL (Tested Offline):

```
<?php
$url = "localhost:8080/?action&p[4]=2&p[7]=5&p[12]=0&p[15]=1";

$arr = explode("&",$url);

foreach(array_slice($arr,1) as $key=>$value)
{

$valArr = explode("=",$value);

$valArr[0] = str_replace("p[","",$valArr[0]);
$valArr[0] = str_replace("]","",$valArr[0]);
echo "Value 1: ". $valArr[0];
echo "<br>";
echo "Value 2: ".$valArr[1];   
echo "<br>";
}

//  Below Output will come:
Value 1: 4
Value 2: 2
Value 1: 7
Value 2: 5
Value 1: 12
Value 2: 0
Value 1: 15
Value 2: 1

?>
```

You will get both the values as required but please make sure that URL structure remains the same.

There might be better solution to resolve your issue but the one I have given is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

PHP automatically converts query-string arguments in the form `param[key]=val&param[foo]=bar` to an associative array: `array (param => array (key => val, foo => bar))`.

With the URL you gave, `var_dump($_GET)` returns:

```
array (size=2)
  'action' => string '' (length=0)
  'p' => 
    array (size=4)
      4 => string '2' (length=1)
      7 => string '5' (length=1)
      12 => string '0' (length=1)
      15 => string '1' (length=1)
```

So you should be able to access the field at index 4 with `$_GET['p'][4]`.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helped me to understand better!